# HTML Border Placement

Tags: html, css

I'm fairly new to Html and am attempting to place items in a list into boxes. However, upon trying to use a style class as opposed to hard writing it for each item, the text is no longer placed within the box. This problem also only occurs when I center the text, which is a requirement. 
Given that it is just a small file I have pasted the entire code into the question.

```css
.EventBorder {
  border: 3px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #287EC7;
  padding: 2em;
}
```

```html
<h1>
  <center>Itineree</center>
</h1>
<h2>
  <center>~ <i>Plan Your Brisbane Event Schedule</i> ~</center>
</h2>

<h4>
  <center>Below is a Visual Itinerary of the Events you have Selected</center>
</h4>

<p class="EventBorder">
  <center>Event 1: This is List Option 1</center>
</p>
<p class="EventBorder">
  <center>Event 2: This is List Option 2</center>
</p>
<p class="EventBorder">
  <center>Event 3: This is List Option 3</center>
</p>
</ul>
```

I just want the text inside the border.

Comment: The only part of a "list" I see is a closing `</ul>` tag. no opening tag or list item tags. Also the `<center>` tag doesn't exist anymore, which seems to be the crux of your issue.

Comment: Instead of using a `center` element, add `text-align: center` to your stylesheet for the `EventBorder` class.

Comment: @j08691 ahh i didn't see that </ul> tag, must have missed it when I changed my list to a set of paragraphs - I didn't want the bullet point to the left of my screen that the list generated. As for the <center> tag it works for my headings so I'm not sure what you mean by 'doesn't exist'. Am I perhaps using an old version?

Comment: @Bobulous Cheers, this worked. I had previously tried using  text-align:center;  but it turns out i was spelling it with 2 L's.

Comment: you can get rid of the bullets with css: list-style-type: none;

Comment: `<center>` isn't a thing anymore so don't use it. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As pointed out by j08691, `<center>` isn't in use anymore. Also - a list element should only contain `<li>` tags.

A better option would be this:

```css
h1, h2, h4 {
    text-align: center;
}

.events {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
}

.events li {
    border: 3px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #287EC7;
    padding: 2em;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<h1>
    Itineree
</h1>
<h2>
    ~ <i>Plan Your Brisbane Event Schedule</i> ~
</h2>

<h4>
    Below is a Visual Itinerary of the Events you have Selected
</h4>

<ul class="events">
    <li>
        Event 1: This is List Option 1
    </li>
    <li>
        Event 2: This is List Option 2
    </li>
    <li>
        Event 3: This is List Option 3
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

Your problem would be revealed if you had [used a validator](https://validator.nu/).

The `<center>` element (which was superseded by CSS in 1996) cannot be a child element of a `<p>` element.

Consequently, the `<center>` start tag implicitly ends the `<p>` element, so it and the text inside it are not inside the `<p>` and are thus outside the border of it.

Comment: +1, this is (so far) the only answer that actually explains the issue. Although I'd found it even more helpful if it included a reference for "implicitly ends the `<p>` element".

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of errors in your HTML, but I recommend getting rid of the center tag and using css instead. Also you have a closing ul tag at the end in your body tag which you should remove.

You can add yourElement{text-align: center} for the same results.

Answer (score 0):

The `<center>` tag [is technically supported](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#special), but it's recommended to  **not** use it anymore. (Thanks @Quentin for clarifying)

You can just remove the tag and instead use `text-align: center` to center the text for the `.EventBorder` class and headers.

```css
h1, h2, h4, .EventBorder{
   text-align: center
}

.EventBorder {
  border: 3px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #287EC7;
  padding: 2em;
}
```

```html
<h1>
  Itineree
</h1>
<h2>
  ~ <i>Plan Your Brisbane Event Schedule</i> ~
</h2>

<h4>
  Below is a Visual Itinerary of the Events you have Selected
</h4>

<p class="EventBorder">
  Event 1: This is List Option 1
</p>
<p class="EventBorder">
  Event 2: This is List Option 2
</p>
<p class="EventBorder">
  Event 3: This is List Option 3
</p>
</ul>
```

Comment: W3Schools is wrong (again), `<center>` [is supported](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#special) (it is just marked that authors should not use it).

Comment: `<center>` isn't supported. [It's obsolete](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/obsolete.html#elementdef-center). _"Elements in the following list are entirely obsolete, and **must not be used by authors**:"_

Comment: @j08691 — It can be both.